# Is possible to hide a .dll extension in a url

Tags: iis, isapi

I'm looking for a trick to hide the .dll extension of an isapi dll in an url. I don't know if this is possible. but I preffer to hide it.

Example
www.mysite.com/test/myapp.dll/testfunction

would be
www.mysite.com/test/myapp/testfunction

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change the link on page to say ww.mysite.com/test/myapp/testfunction and use the following config with [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/):

RewriteBase/

RewriteRule ^test/myapp/testfunction$ /test/myapp.dll/testfunction [NC,L]

Answer (score 1):

You can write ISAPI filter and change the URI as you like. There are, of course, ready [commercial](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) and [free](http://www.motobit.com/help/url-replacer-rewriter/iis-mod-rewrite.asp) ones

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150963.aspx) may be of use

EDIT: The link above is actually confusing as I don't think it solves the problem at hand.

These two links 
this [One](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2007/04/29/serve-extensionless-url-from-asp-net-without-using-isapi-module-or-iis-6-wildcard-mapping.aspx) requires some coding, 
this [One](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true) requires some IIS Setup

Answer (score 0):

In [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com),  a free URL rewriter for IIS5/6/7, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule  ^/test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /test/$1.dll/$2   [I,L]
```

This rule has wild-card matching on the DLL name and function.

Lots more possibilities, too.